# How to print the Divisors alone??

Tags: java

I want to find out how many divisors a given real number has and want to print those divisors.But i get error :
Enter a positive integer: 25

The number of divisors of 25 is 1
And the divisors are1

The number of divisors of 25 is 1
And the divisors are1

The number of divisors of 25 is 1
And the divisors are1

The number of divisors of 25 is 1
And the divisors are1

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 2
And the divisors are2

The number of divisors of 25 is 3
And the divisors are3

Keeps getting printed over and over again.
program works fine and tells how many divisors the number has.But when i try to print out each of those numbers and show them,problem.Is an array necessary?   WIll a great mind out there help me solve this?
NOT HOMEWORK

Here is my source code

```
public class CountDivisors {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int N; // A positive integer entered by the user.
// Divisors of this number will be counted.
int testDivisor; // A number between 1 and N that is a
// possible divisor of N.
int divisorCount; // Number of divisors of N that have been found.
int numberTested; // Used to count how many possible divisors
int positiveDivisor;
// of N have been tested. When the number
// reaches 1000000, a period is output and
// the value of numberTested is reset to zero.
/* Get a positive integer from the user. */
while (true) {
System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
N = TextIO.getlnInt();
if (N > 0)
break;
System.out.println("That number is not positive. Please try again.");
}
/* Count the divisors, printing a "." after every 1000000 tests. */
divisorCount = 0;
numberTested = 0;
positiveDivisor=0;
for (testDivisor = 1; testDivisor <= N; testDivisor++) {

if ( N % testDivisor == 0 )
{
positiveDivisor++;
divisorCount++;
numberTested++;
if (numberTested == 1000000) {
System.out.println("Whoof!! Just tested a Million Numbers!!");
System.out.println("No probs.LETS GO AGAIN!!");
numberTested = 0;
}
}
/* Display the result. */
System.out.println();
System.out.println("The number of divisors of " + N
+ " is " + divisorCount);
System.out.println("And the divisors are" + positiveDivisor);
} // end main()
} // end class CountDivisors
}
```

Comment: First of all you should indent your code.

Comment: Still looks like a homework...

Comment: You have three curly braces at the end--the first says `end main`, the second says `end class CountDivisors`, and the third one--what is that the end of?  That should be a clue right there that your curly braces aren't matched correctly, especially if you had to add an extra one at the end to get it to compile.  Check carefully.  Indenting (as Eran suggested) would really help.  If you're using an IDE that can do the indentation for you, then let it.

Comment: its not homework.i am learning java and am curious on how to do this for myself

Comment: i am using eclipse.it is indented.the program works fine and says "number of divisors of x is y".but i want to print those numbers.show them.DO I NEED AN ARRAY FOR THAT or a better idea??

Comment: If you want to store/use a collection of things then yes.

Comment: thank you for clearing that upTakendarkk  :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a few issues in your code, first I added a `Scanner` because I don't have your `TextIO` class. Next, I added a `List` to store the divisors (since you only kept a count). So, it should look something like -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int testDivisor;
    int numberTested; // Used to count how many possible divisors
    int N = -1;
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        N = scanner.nextInt();
        if (N > 0) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("That number is not positive. Please try again.");
    }
    /* Count the divisors, printing a "." after every 1000000 tests. */
    numberTested = 0;
    List<Integer> divisors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (testDivisor = 1; testDivisor <= N; testDivisor++) {
        if (N % testDivisor == 0) {
            divisors.add(testDivisor);
            numberTested++;
            if (numberTested == 1000000) {
                System.out.println("Whoof!! Just tested a Million Numbers!!");
                System.out.println("No probs.LETS GO AGAIN!!");
                numberTested = 0;
            }
        }
        /* Display the result. */
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The number of divisors of " + N + " is "
                + divisors.size());
        System.out.println("And the divisors are" + divisors);
    }
} // end main()
```

When I test with 25 I do get (excluding the intermediate steps) -

```
The number of divisors of 25 is 3
And the divisors are[1, 5, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'for' loop is printing the statement "The number of divisors of N is" many times.
Try storing all divisors in an ArrayList and after the for loop put another 'for' loop to print those.

```
.
.
.
ArrayList<int> divisor_array = new ArrayList<int>();
for (testDivisor = 1; testDivisor <= N; testDivisor++) {

  if ( N % testDivisor == 0 ) {
    positiveDivisor++;
    divisorCount++;
    numberTested++;
    divisor_array.add(testDivisor);

    if (numberTested == 1000000) {
      System.out.println("Whoof!! Just tested a Million Numbers!!");
      System.out.println("No probs.LETS GO AGAIN!!");
      numberTested = 0;
    }
  }
} //end the for loop here

/* Display the result. */
System.out.println();
System.out.println("The number of divisors of " + N + " is " + divisorCount);

//print all divisors
System.out.println("And the divisors are:");
for(int k : divisor_array) {
   System.out.println(k);
}
```

Comment: what am i supposed to enter in <int> ??? a number? how do i know the bounds? if i use your line,eclipse is telling me to "insert "dimensions" here" ???

Comment: i am asking  @truffleme as you have bypassed the TextIO class problem.... please reply

Comment: nvm i just used default eclipse fix and imported the ArrayList package from java.util. Works perfectly and is exactly what i wanted.I am continuing my learning and hope i will one day be as smart as truffleme and rest of you guys here and be that well versed in java.Thanks a mill guys.never expected to get resolved so soon and learnt something new.Will be back for more.

Comment: how do i resolve this question as truffleme has answered it??